# How would I configure my javascript function to convert date to dd/MMM/yyyy format upon binding from database to an mvc control?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have written a function in javascript to convert date to the specific format but I want it to convert my date to dd/MMM/yyyy format i.e. 01/Jul/2019.

```
  function formatDate(dateVal = "") {
        if (dateVal == null || dateVal == '')
        {
            return '';
        }
        else
        {
            var date = new Date(parseInt(dateVal.replace('/Date(', '')))
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = date.getDate();
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            return (day.toString().length > 1 ? day : "0" + day) + "/" + (month.toString().length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/" + year;
        }

    }
```

e.g. if a date from db is coming like this `2019-07-24 00:00:00.000` then it should convert it to dd/MMM/yyyy.

mvc control:

Update:

the date is coming from database but before binding it to the textbox it's in json format i.e. /Date(1563220800000)/.

Comment: Just convert the date from the db to a new Date() then run it through your formatDate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DB is outputting `2019-07-24 00:00:00.00`, this is close to the needed parse format. Consider the following:

```js
function formatDate(dateStr) {
  if (dateStr == null || dateStr == '' || dateStr == undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  var dt;
  if(!isNaN(dateStr)){
    dt = parseInt(dateStr);
  } else if(dateStr[0] =="/"){
    dt = parseInt(dateStr.slice(6,-2));
  } else {
    dt = Date.parse(dateStr); // Output: 1563951600000
  }
  var date = new Date(dt); // Output: Date Object (2019-07-24T07:00:00.000Z)
  var mm = date.getMonth();
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var yy = date.getFullYear();
  var MMM = months[mm];
  dd = (dd < 10 ? "0" + dd : dd);
  return dd + "/" + MMM + "/" + yy;
}

console.log("1: " + formatDate("/Date(1563220800000)/"));
console.log("2: " + formatDate("2019-07-24 00:00:00.000"));
console.log("3: " + formatDate("1562019448869"));
```

You can then use it like so:

```
$('#InspectionReport_InspectionDate').val(formatDate(data.InspectionReport.InspectionDate));
```

**Update**

I have adjusted so that it can accept 3 different formats. 1. It can accept the EPOCH Time 2. It can accept "/DATE(EPOCH)/" (FYI - this is not JSON). 3. It can accept an ISO Time.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot but I need the format i.e. 24/Jul/2019.

Comment: @Stacky your Code example did not suggest that with the output you have. I had missed the note below. Updated answer.

Comment: alright. thanks a lot. So as far as this format is coming from the database, it will be converted to dd/MMM/yyyy using the function above... right? Or for any other format too?

Comment: @Stacky https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse "*A string representing a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format (other formats may be used, but results are implementation-dependent).*"

Comment: for me this is not working coming as Nan/Nan/Nan. 

the date is returning from json object as /Date(1563220800000)/.

Comment: I tried to convert it using my old method (posted) + yours i.e. yourmethod(oldmethod(jsondate)); return Nan/Nan/Nan

Comment: @Stacky what is being returned by `data.InspectionReport.InspectionDate` ?

Comment: /Date(1563220800000)/

Comment: @Stacky the `formatDate()` is expecting a String entry that is `"2019-07-24 00:00:00.00"` as you stated in your Post. It cannot understand `"/Date(15632208000000)/"` as this is not an ISO Date Format. You said: *date from db is coming like this `2019-07-24 00:00:00.000` then it should convert it to `dd/MMM/yyyy`* So please ensure your passing the detail to the function.

Comment: hi, updated my question. Before binding to textbox it is like this /Date(1563220800000)/. So I want it in dd/MMM/yyyy format. Please help me on this as I have spent whole day trying

Comment: @Stacky I have updated my answer. FYI, `/DATE(1563220800000)/` is not JSON. It looks more like an SQL Function.

Answer (score 0):

When you are binding the field to the value in your model you should use one of the facilities of the ToString() method for the Date or DateTime.
`model.InspectionReport.InspectionDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")`

`DisplayFormat` attribute can also be used to declare the formatting in the model.

Comment: I did the first one but no effect.